# Suppose the correlation coefficient between $x$ and $y$ is denoted by $R$ and that between $x$ and $(y+x)$ by $R_1$

Tags: regression, correlation, econometrics

How are we supposed to judge whether​ $R$ and $R_1$ are related and if they are, then how?

Comment: Consider the 2-dimensional linear space generated by centered X and Y. The correlation is the cosine of the angle between the corresponding vectors.

Comment: How would we judge if they're related?

Comment: You may draw it on the plane to understand that $R_1\ge R$. Moreover, $R_1=R$ only if centered $x$ and $y$ are collinear.

Answer (score 3):

$R$ and $R_1$ are related, and here's how:

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}}$ $\newcommand{\var}{\mathrm{Var}}$ $\newcommand{\cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}$ $$R=\frac{\cov(x,y)}{\sqrt{\var(x)\var(y)}}$$

$$R_1=\frac{\cov(x,x+y)}{\sqrt{\var(x)\var(x+y)}}=\frac{\var(x)+\cov(x,y)}{\sqrt{\var(x)\big(\var(x)+\var(y)+2\cov(x,y)\big)}}$$

We see they can both be computed from the same set of 3 statistics: the variances of $x$ and $y$, and the covariance between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: So can we say that $R\gt R_1$ ?

Comment: You can say $R_1 \ge R$ actually

Comment: Considering the equation in your answer, $R_1$ has a denominator greater than $R$ by a difference greater than how much $R_1$ 's numerator is greater than $R$, which implies $R\gt R_1$. Then how can we say $R_1 \ge R$?